# Differentiability of projection of a radial function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let's consider a radial function $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, that is $f$ is actually just a function of the radius, that is $f(\vec x) = g(\Vert \vec x \Vert_2)$ for some $g$.

Furthermore $f \in C^k$, i.e. that $f$ is $k$ times continuously differentiable (i.e. all $\partial^\alpha f$ are continuous for the multi index $\vert \alpha \vert \leq k$).

Now consider the projection

$$ p(x) = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x, y) dy$$

Can we now make a claim that $p$ is also in $C^m$ for some $m$ dependent on $k$? My gut feeling is that $m \geq k$, but I don't know how to show it.

I wonder whether we could make first a claim about $g$, and then represent $g$ in terms of some basis that lets us go to $p$, but I had trouble already with the first step, and then also wasn't sure if there is a better representation of $g$. But maybe this is also not the best approach to begin with. In any case I'd be happy for any hints!